# How to generate the font enum for a custom icon font in vaadin

Tags: java, vaadin

I am trying to use a custom icon font in my vaadin application. I am following the guidelines provided in [this](https://vaadin.com/web/vaadin/wiki/-/wiki/10674/Font+Icons,+FontAwesome+and+custom+icon+fonts) page.

What I have trouble with is generating the java enum for font.

In this page it says,

> (Note that you can easily generate the enum from the list of icons in
>   the zip downloaded from IcoMoon.)

But I have no idea how I can generate this enum with the icomoon zip file I downloaded. May be I am missing some basic knowledge the page has assumed to posses by its reader.

Can someone tell me how to generate the icon enum?

Comment: have you checked the section "3. Make use of the icons in Java" of the link you posted in the question?, it provides an example

Comment: @saljuama yes it provides an example. But it is not practical to write code manually for a large icon set (the page says it can be generated, but doesn't say how). Also, the page doesn't mention where it got the enum value from. eg: `RIBBON(0xe009)`

Comment: the value you can get it from the style.css file inside the downloaded zip, at the end, you get all the hexadecimal codes.  Wether is practical or not, the guide says it is required i'm afraid.

Comment: if you have dozens of icons, perhaps would be appropiate to write a small parser of the css file and output the java code which you can then include in your `enum`

Comment: So that's what vaadin considers `easy`!. I will try to write a script for this. May be recording a macro in notepad++ might be easier.

Comment: The Vaadin project uses a script for this: https://github.com/vaadin/vaadin/blob/master/scripts/generateFontAwesomeEnum.sh

Answer (score 3):

I faced the same challenge and wrote a class for this, which automatically converts the selection.js from the IcoMoon zip to a fully and complete Vaadin-compatible Java-enum ;-)

Feel free to reuse. It only requires the json-simple jar from https://code.google.com/archive/p/json-simple/downloads

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Iterator;

import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;
import org.json.simple.parser.ParseException;

public class JSONTools {

    public static void convertIcoMoonJSON2EnumClass(String filename) {

        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();

        StringBuilder returnTxt = new StringBuilder();

        returnTxt.append("public enum IcoMoon implements FontIcon {\n\n");

        try {

            Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader(filename));

            JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;
            // loop array
            JSONArray msg = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("icons");
            Iterator<JSONObject> iterator = msg.iterator();
            int i = 0;
            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                JSONObject iterator_current = iterator.next();

                JSONObject icon = (JSONObject) iterator_current.get("icon");
                // System.out.println(icon);

                JSONArray tags = (JSONArray) icon.get("tags");
                returnTxt.append(((String) tags.get(0)).toUpperCase().replace("-", "_"));

                returnTxt.append("(");

                JSONObject properties = (JSONObject) iterator_current.get("properties");
                long code = (Long) properties.get("code");
                returnTxt.append(code);
                returnTxt.append(")");

                returnTxt.append(",\n");

                // System.out.println(icon);
            }
            returnTxt.append(";\n");

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        returnTxt.append("\r\n" + 
                "   private final int codepoint;\r\n" + 
                "   // This must match (S)CSS\r\n" + 
                "   private final String fontFamily = \"IcoMoon\";\r\n" + 
                "\r\n" + 
                "   IcoMoon(int codepoint) {\r\n" + 
                "       this.codepoint = codepoint;\r\n" + 
                "   }\r\n" + 
                "\r\n" + 
                "   @Override\r\n" + 
                "   public String getFontFamily() {\r\n" + 
                "       return fontFamily;\r\n" + 
                "   }\r\n" + 
                "\r\n" + 
                "   @Override\r\n" + 
                "   public int getCodepoint() {\r\n" + 
                "       return codepoint;\r\n" + 
                "   }\r\n" + 
                "\r\n" + 
                "   @Override\r\n" + 
                "   public String getHtml() {\r\n" + 
                "       return \"<span class=\\\"v-icon IcoMoon\\\">&#x\" + Integer.toHexString(codepoint) + \";</span>\";\r\n" + 
                "   }\r\n" + 
                "\r\n" + 
                "   @Override\r\n" + 
                "   public String getMIMEType() {\r\n" + 
                "       // Font icons are not real resources\r\n" + 
                "       throw new UnsupportedOperationException(\r\n" + 
                "               FontIcon.class.getSimpleName() + \" should not be used where a MIME type is needed.\");\r\n" + 
                "   }\r\n" + 
                "\r\n" + 
                "}");

        System.out.println(returnTxt);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        convertIcoMoonJSON2EnumClass("path_to_your_selection.json");
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution. I got this done by a notepad++ macro. I will use your solution when I am adding some more icons to my font.